# ASP.NET Web API C# Concurrent Requests Causing Duplicates in Database

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi Async controller method that calls another async method that first does a null check to see if a record exists, and if it doesn't add it to database. Problem is if I have say 3 requests come in at the same time all the null checks happen at once in various threads (i'm assuming) and I will get 2 duplicate entries. For example:

```
 public async void DoSomething()
{
    var record = {query that returns record or null}
    if (record == null)
    {
        AddNewRecordToDatabase();
    }   
}
```

... This seems like a very common thing and maybe I'm missing something, but how do I prevent this from happening? I have to purposely try to get it to create duplicates of course, but it is a requirement to not allow it to do so.

Thanks in advance,

Lee

Comment: Take a look at this link. It describes how to implement a optimistic locking mechanism using EntityFramework. The other option would be to use a Mutex.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @Matt Optimistic locking is a good approach for updates, but I'm not sure how it would work for inserts, since there is no record that you'd check for changes.

Comment: OP: Two questions. (1) What is the desired behavior? If two users add the same thing at once, do you want two records added, but you just need to make sure the identifiers are unique? Or do you want the 2nd user to see an error?  (2) Are you using any sort of entity framework, or using direct SQL calls?

Comment: @John Wu - Well it's not users as much as the same endpoint being concurrently hit with the same request. If the record doesn't exist, I want to add it. If it does exist, I just want to ignore it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this by putting unique constraints in the data layer. Assuming your data source is sql, you can put a unique constraint across the columns you are querying by with "query that returns record or null" and it will prevent these duplicates. The problem with using a lock or a mutex, is that it doesn't scale across multiple instances of the service. You should be able to deploy many instances of your service (to different machines), have any of those instances handle requests, and still have consistent behavior. A mutex or lock isn't going to protect you from this concurrency issue in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I prevent this from happening with async calls by calling a stored procedure instead.
The stored procedure then makes the check, via a "On duplicate key detection" or a similar query for MSSQL db.

That way, it's merely the order of the async calls that gets to determine which is a create, and which is not.

Comment: This is the best way to do it, if your development team is comfortable writing stored procedures; it will perform the best and have the most throughput for high volume sites due to the locality of the lock.

Comment: Thank I will look into this however, the method that performs the update also performs a bunch of other related inserts, so I would have to consider moving all that logic to the stored procedure as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are several answers to this, depending on the details and what your team is comfortable with.

- The best and most performant answer it to modify your c# code so that instead of calling a CRUD database operation it calls a stored procedure that you write. The stored procedure would check for existence and insert or update only as needed. The specifics are completely under your control, since you write the code.
- If you want to stick with ordinary CRUD operations, you can force the database to serialize the requests one after the other by wrapping them in a transaction and using a strict transaction isolation level. On SQL Server you'd want to use serializable. This will prevent any transaction from altering the state of the table in the short time between the part where you check for existence and when you insert the record. See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx) for a list of transaction isolation levels and how to apply them in c# code. If you do this there is a risk of deadlock, so you'll need to `catch` and swallow those specific errors.
- If your only need it to ensure uniqueness, and the new record has a [natural (not surrogate) key](http://www.itprotoday.com/business-intelligence/surrogate-key-vs-natural-key), you can add a uniqueness constraint on the key, which will prevent the second insert from succeeding. This solution doesn't work so well with surrogate keys; it doesn't really solve the problem, it just relocates it to the surrogate key generation process. But if you have a decent natural key, this is very easy to implement.

Comment: In SQL Server using SERIALIZABLE here will prevent duplicates, but will produce deadlocks instead of duplicates.  To properly serialize the transactions, you must use an UPDLOCK (possibly in addition to SERIALIZABLE to force range locks).

Comment: "The ability to specify the UPDLOCK hints on tables that are targets of INSERT statements will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. These hints do not affect the performance of INSERT statements. Avoid using them in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them." [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). It's true you'll get some deadlocks-- not always, only if the timing is just so-- and OP will need to catch and swallow those. Don't think that's avoidable.

Comment: The UPDLOCK goes on the SELECT that searches for duplicates, not on the INSERT.  And if you are willing to catch errors, then just put a unique constraint on the columns, and catch the key violations.

Comment: You can’t lock a record that doesn’t exist. Uniqueness constraint is covered in the third bullet, along with its limitations.

Comment: You certainly _can_ lock a record that doesn't exist.  That's exactly what SERIALIZABLE (or HOLDLOCK) does.  It's just that without the UPDLOCK the range locks are S locks, and both sessions can acquire the same one.